# update mongo throws ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, dictionary, mongo-java

I search a lot of methods to solve the problems for a long time , but the methods also can't solve my problem,so need your help to solve this problem, thank you very very much!

**The exception stack :**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:977)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1012)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putIterable(BSONEncoder.java:258)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:198)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:140)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:190)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putIterable(BSONEncoder.java:259)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:198)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:140)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:190)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:140)
at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:86)
at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:190)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.update(DBApiLayer.java:341)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:150)
at com.autonavi.sns.util.TileCache.updateToMongo(TileCache.java:589)
at com.autonavi.sns.util.TileCache.updatePoint(TileCache.java:349)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.function.UpdatePointFunc.updatePoint(UpdatePointFunc.java:82)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.function.UpdatePointFunc.doExec(UpdatePointFunc.java:37)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.function.SNSFunction.execFunc(SNSFunction.java:42)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.function.SNSFunction.execFunc(SNSFunction.java:45)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.function.SNSFunction.execFunc(SNSFunction.java:45)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.function.SNSFunction.execFunc(SNSFunction.java:45)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.function.SNSFunction.execFunc(SNSFunction.java:45)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.SNSWorkFlow.startExec(SNSWorkFlow.java:45)
at com.autonavi.sns.workflow.SNSWorkFlow.execute(SNSWorkFlow.java:31)
at com.autonavi.sns.service.SNSThreadHandler.serviceDispacth(SNSThreadHandler.java:79)
at com.autonavi.sns.service.SNSThreadHandler.run(SNSThreadHandler.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Set update key :**

```
BasicDBObject udbo = new BasicDBObject();
udbo.put(ConstantUtil.MONGO_ID_KEY, tileId);

List<BasicDBObject> plist = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
for (PointBasic p : points) {
    BasicDBObject pkey = new BasicDBObject();
    boolean isPhysic = p.isPhysicPoint();
    pkey.put("isphysic", isPhysic);
    pkey.put("x", p.getX());
    pkey.put("y", p.getY());
    pkey.put("picurl", p.getPicUrl());
    pkey.put("area", p.getArea());
    plist.add(pkey);
}

BasicDBObject pdbo = new BasicDBObject();
pdbo.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("point", plist));

return this.updateToMongo(udbo, pdbo, TILE_LAYER);
```

**Update keys to mongo :**

```
private boolean updateToMongo(BasicDBObject udbo, BasicDBObject ukey, long layer) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        this.mongo = MongoDatabaseUtil.getInstance();
        this.coll = mongo.getCollection(ConstantUtil.TILE_COLL + layer);
        this.coll.update(udbo, ukey, true, true);
        flag = true;
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        LOG.error("Mongo error : ", e);
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to be sure, but I *suspect* that your application is multi-threaded, and that some other thread is updating the `BasicDBObject` while the current thread is calling `updateToMongo`.

There's no magic solution to this.  You have to stop other threads from updating the in-memory copy while you are persisting it.

---

> Yes,my application is multi-threaded,but every thread calling updateToMongo in a new class, then the BasicDBObject will affect updateToMongo method?

I don't think it is relevant that the calls to `updateToMongo` happen "in" a different class or different instance.  The problem is happening (I'm guessing) because one thread is updating a given `BasicDBObject` instance while another thread is trying to persist the same instance.  (In theory it could even be the same thread doing this ... but that scenario is a bit far-fetched.)

Comment: Yes,my application is multi-threaded,but every thread calling updateToMongo in a new class, then the BasicDBObject will affect  updateToMongo method? thank you !

Comment: Yes, you are right, the MongoDatabaseUtil is a Singleton,and the and will get only one DBCollection with the collName,when I call the method updateToMongo

Answer (score 0):

You're using a for-each loop to iterate over your 'points' collection.
If your application is multithreaded and you modify (add, remove, etc) the 'points' collection you will get this error.

You have a couple options.
First, is to use a regular for loop and retrieve the object with the current index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
   PointBasic p = points.get(i); // could be different depending upon your collection type.
   ...
}
```

However, if you do modify the points collection while you're iterating, you may skip some data and you won't know about it :O
If this operation is mandatory, then try synchronizing the code.
(Synchronizing code makes sure that code which is wrapped in the same block, will never be executed at the same time across threads.)

```
<global>
private Object pointsLock = new Object();
</global>

synchronized (pointsLock) {
   for (PointBasic p : points) {
      BasicDBObject pkey = new BasicDBObject();
      boolean isPhysic = p.isPhysicPoint();
      pkey.put("isphysic", isPhysic);
      pkey.put("x", p.getX());
      pkey.put("y", p.getY());
      pkey.put("picurl", p.getPicUrl());
      pkey.put("area", p.getArea());
      plist.add(pkey);
   }
}
```

Wrap any code that modifies 'points' async in the same synchronized block.
Also, make sure that you synchronize using the same lock object.

You could also use an Iterator (don't recommend at all), or a while loop but in the end they do about the same thing as the for loop and probably less efficient.

I didn't exactly follow the stack trace given, but it does say something about updating points so I'm hoping I didn't post completely unrelated material. :)

Comment: Yep, I think the other response got it correct. The problem doesn't look to be in the for loop of their code from the stack-trace but that BasicDBObject is derived from HashMap which is not thread-safe.

Comment: @ScottHernandez - it is not exactly a thread-safety issue.  `HashMap` could be thread-safe, and *still* not support modification concurrent with an iteration.

Comment: @ScottHernandez you could be right, I've just experienced this exception a lot when using foreach loops and the moment I saw that foreach loop iterating over a list which wasn't included in the code he provided, who knows where he may be using it.